# AX200 wifi does not work with ubuntu 18.04 (razer 15)

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

Tried updated kernel to 5.1 and 5.2. Currently:

```
uname -a
... 5.1.21-050121-generic ...
```

I also installed the latest firmware:

```
ls /lib/firmware/ | grep iwlwifi-cc-a0
iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode
```

Running out of ideas here... Also confirmed that secure boot is disabled.

```
dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[] iwlwifi: 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Let me know what else I can check. Considering returning the laptop (razer 15) at this point since I need ubuntu running on it.

Answer (score 0):

I went out and got a usb-ethernet adapter (LIFE SAVER! Will cherish this thing) and doing a `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`.

I then updated to kernel 5.1.16 and put the latest firmware for AX200 into my `/lib/firmware` directory. I don't know which step absolutely fixed it (doing `apt-get update/upgrade` or using kernel 5.1.16 specifically; but I think it was the former probably), but it now magically works:

```
dmesg | grep wifi
[    3.164561] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.175839] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 46.3cfab8da.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.196234] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
```

Hopefully this will help others to get this working because I was on the verge of returning this laptop...